# Sweet Basil-Pest Infestation

Tags: pests, basil

I know my sweet basil plants are infested with white creepy crawlies. Are these whiteflies? (Click on the photo to zoom in)
[image]

Where do these creepy crawlies come from? I am growing the basil on the balcony of my sixth-floor apartment. Do you think it might be because of a small compost pot that I have on the balcony too?

I am not sure I can save any of my plants. The other ones show fewer of these white creepy crawlies but I am sure more are hidden. The question I have is for future batches of sweet basil, what can I do to prevent these infestation. I am thinking of growing these under a fine insect-proof mesh or moving it completely indoors into one the bedrooms which still get a bit of light.

Comment: I've had white flies on basil before. They congregate on the bottom of the leaves and then fly away when shaken. Not as damaging as this pest!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If, as seems likely to me, like this:

[image: Woolly aphid]
(*Image courtesy Tmaq97*)

They are [Eriosomatinae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eriosomatinae) (woolly aphids] rather than [whiteflies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitefly). They can be [dealt with](https://www.rhs.org.uk/advice/profile?pid=181) fairly easily. Those that don’t just wash off can be sprayed with 'horticultural' soap (that is, not a detergent) and, where available, neem oil.

These insects fly/are blown around in the atmosphere. Your plants should be salvageable and I'd not bother with a mesh or moving indoors. Depending on where you are more sunlight may be better overall and a mesh might do more to keep out  their predators than the aphids.

ON THE OTHER HAND

If this (about the same size as the aphid above):

[image: Mealybug](*Image courtesy D-Kuru*)

(or similar but with no significant tail) then likely a mealybug ([Pseudococcidae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mealybug)). Insecticidal soap will work against both aphids and mealybugs.

Comment: Is your photo that of a mature wooly aphids? I don't seem to see wings. Also, what else could be considered a horticultural soap? Normal soap water?